# Audio transfer real time via bluetooth socket c++

Tags: c++, linux, qt, sockets, bluetooth

I'm trying to communicate between 2 devices using bluetooth sockets and rfcomm but my program crashes (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMzux.png) for error image).

I just listen about 1 or 2 second and then the project just crashes.

This is my client sending audio:

```
void ClientTalk::startTalk()
{
    qDebug() << "Start talk";

    audio_output->stop();
    connect(audio_input, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)), this, SLOT(handleStateChangedInput(QAudio::State)));

    audio_input->start(socket);

    qDebug() << "Talking to server";
}
```

And this is my client listening to server:

```
void ClientTalk::readSocket()
{
    //QBuffer *buffer;
    QByteArray buff;

    audio_input->stop();

    connect(audio_output, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)), this, SLOT(handleStateChangedOutput(QAudio::State)));


    while(socket->canReadLine())
    {
        buff.append(socket->readLine());
        QBuffer audio_buffer(&buff);
        audio_buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        //QDataStream s(buff, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
        audio_output->start(&audio_buffer);
        qDebug() << buff << endl;
    }
    buff.clear()
}
```

And this is my server talk and listen:

```
void ServerTalk::readSocket()
{
    QBluetoothSocket *socket = qobject_cast<QBluetoothSocket *>(sender());
    if (!socket)
        return;

    //QBuffer *buffer;

    audio_input->stop();
    QByteArray buff;

    connect(audio_output, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)), this, SLOT(handleStateChangedOutput(QAudio::State)));

    while(socket->canReadLine())
    {
        buff.append(socket->readLine());
        QBuffer audio_buffer(&buff);
        audio_buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        //QDataStream s(buff, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
        audio_output->start(&audio_buffer);
        qDebug() << buff << endl;
    }
    buff.clear();
}
```

And I have a button to start talk and listen:

```
connect(btn_talk, SIGNAL(pressed()), server, SLOT(startTalk()));
connect(btn_talk, SIGNAL(released()), server, SLOT(readSocket()));
```

Comment: Try to use Valgrind.

Comment: It just say I lost some data out of package